# Are NodeJs applications crawlable by search engines?

Tags: node.js, pug

If I use Jades template engine with NodeJs will the app be crawlable by search engines and Facebook without using the `_escaped_fragment_`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application outputs HTML, it is no different than if you had written that HTML in a file and simply served the file. The wider Web doesn't generally know or care what you're using to generate your HTML.

(It is possible to infer what tech a page is using by inspecting headers and looking for common idioms that are unique to a particular technology, but these are just clues, not a fundamental difference in what your Web page is.)